# importing a library that contains a same "namespaces" as Scala Option

Tags: scala

I'm going to use [Args4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/args4j) java library to parse command line arguments, but while importing the library: `import org.kohsuke.args4j.{CmdLineException, CmdLineParser, Option}` it steps over the scala Option.

As I use Option in the same file, I end up having issues as the scala Option is being recognized as an Args4j Option.

I solved it by importing the Args4j lib inside the Object I actually going to use it, but I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this allowing me to have all imports grouped on top.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "rename" type during import:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.{CmdLineException, CmdLineParser, Option => ArgOption}
```

to avoid clashes.

```
Object[A]
ArgObject
```

Other thing would be importing package instead of its elements:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j

Option[A]
arg4j.Option
```

or use full name for Scala's option

```
scala.Option[A]
Option
```

Comment: Ahh renaming is perfect! Thanks!